# Width 100% not working on iOS

Tags: css, ios

For some reason on the iphone, my footer doesn't stretch across the screen, even though it's css is set to width: 100%. You can view an example of my footer issue here:  http://pixelcakecreative.com/tla2/

My css for the footer is as follows:

```
#footer{ width:100%; margin-top:100px; position:relative; clear:left; background:#4c4c4c; float:left; padding:30px 0;}
```

This problem ONLY applies to iOS devices, as the layout works fine on PC browsers. Any idea how to fix this? I have tried everything I can think of. Thanks!

Comment: as it turns out, the solution is to change the viewport width to the width of the website container:  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1010" />  however, it looks like it loads fine, and then a split-second later, the iphone scales it down just a bit so there is extra room to the right. Check out the site now to see what I mean

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try by simplifying your meta name viewport (at least for iOS) to the following line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

Less attributes than you are normally told to have, I know, but it has worked for my mobile projects.

Now, upon closer inspection, the majority if your site is under 'center', and then you have wrapper and footer.

The code used for the wrapper and the footer is different. Wrapper has a fixed `width:941px;` whereas footer just has `width:100%`. The majority of the elements inside wrapper have `width:100%` but that only works because wrapper has `width: 941px`.

So, you either try adding that same width and padding to footer `{width:941px; padding:30px 34px;}` or something along those lines OR

You throw footer inside a similar wrapper with a fixed with, padding, etc and then let let footer keep `width:100%;`

Comment: which of the two parts fixed it for you? I assume the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the mobile viewport meta tag
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

This is needed so mobile devices such as iOS properly scale the page to the viewport. You can [read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) or [here](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag).

Comment: I already have that in my head section. It looks like it loads at first then removes a good part of the footer...strange.

Comment: @JCHASE11 Remove the ending / on your opening html tag. That doesn't belong there.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that didn't do it

Answer (score 1):

your `div#innerFooter` is preventing the footer to scale properly, adjust the width to 100% and that should fix it

```
#innerFooter {width:100%}
```

Comment: No, this doesnt fix it, actually further screws it up. It looks like the problem is the footer, not the innerFooter.

Comment: it has to do with the viewport width. Currently it is set to: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving initial-scale and maximum-scale empty and use user-scrollable=no. The first two let to the same error in a project of ours with responsive design. I haven't figured out why yet.